# What does this mean by "all http command all idempotent except POST"?

Tags: http, rest

I came across this question today. Does it only mean except for POST, other http methods can do multiple times?

Comment: "Idempotence is the property of certain operations in mathematics and computer science, that they can be applied multiple times without changing the result beyond the initial application."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idempotence is defined in [Section 9.1.2 of RFC 2616](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.9.1.2). Also, the statement is incorrect. There are many other non-idempotent HTTP methods, see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-method-registrations-09.html#rfc.section.A.